# How to save two numpy array with original dtype/precisions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, precision

I have two numpy arrays: one is *float* , another one is *uint64*. When I stack them with the **np.c_** , **np.hstack** or **np.concentrate** , the values of *uint64* array are changed.  How to stack them and write them into a text file correctly ?

```
import numpy as np
a= np.array([11112222333344445555,11112222333344445556])
b = np.array([1.0,2.0])
c = np.c_[a,b]
np.savetxt('test',c,fmt="%22i %12.6f")
```

The numbers saved in the test file are

```
11112222333344446464     1.000000
11112222333344446464     2.000000
```

Of course, I can save them with a loop. But I wonder there is a more pythonic way.

Comment: Does this answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/26019097

Comment: Does this answer your question? [numpy: is it possible to preserve the dtype of columns when using column\_stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018781/numpy-is-it-possible-to-preserve-the-dtype-of-columns-when-using-column-stack)

Comment: @SurajSubramanian Thanks! The new array seems fine. But it still could not be saved correctly with the savetxt, which works if I save them separately .

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
strfmta = np.vectorize(lambda x: "%1s" % x)
strfmtb = np.vectorize(lambda x: "%1.6f" % x)

a = np.array([11112222333344445555, 11112222333344445556])
b = np.array([1.0, 2.0])

a = strfmta(a)
b = strfmtb(b)

c = np.c_[a, b]
np.savetxt('test', c, fmt="%22s %12s")
```

Output of `test` file:

```
  11112222333344445555     1.000000
  11112222333344445556     2.000000
```

Comment: Thank you! I never use this function. It works like a charm ~

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a better solution

```
import numpy as np
a= np.array([11112222333344445555,11112222333344445556])
b = np.array([1.0,2.0])
c = np.c_[a.astype('S32'),b]
np.savetxt('test',np.char.decode(c),fmt="%s")
```

The result is

```
11112222333344445555 1.0
11112222333344445556 2.0
```