# how to join by stack multiple types in numpy arrays

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
arr2 = np.array(['n', 'b', 'c', 'y', 'f', 'j', 'p'])

l = np.stack((arr1, arr2), axis=1)
print(l)
```

the output is:

[image]

i would like that the types will be like the input so that the output will be:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Numpy tries to generalize to a single type for each array. It gets more tricky if you want sections of the array to be a different python `type` than others. If you really want to preserve the dtype of the arrays, then there are a number of other threads that address this:

[Store different datatypes in one NumPy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309739/store-different-datatypes-in-one-numpy-array)

[numpy: is it possible to preserve the dtype of columns when using column_stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018781/numpy-is-it-possible-to-preserve-the-dtype-of-columns-when-using-column-stack)